# How can I fix unable to resolve dependency tree while installing ESLint

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I'm getting error messages while installing ESLint for my TypeScript/React project. There is no log file or anything else.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: website@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @typescript-eslint/parser@5.62.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/parser@"^5.62.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^6.0.0 || ^6.0.0-alpha" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@6.19.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Steps to reproduce:

```bash
npx create-react-app one client --template typescript
npm add eslint --dev
npm add @typescript-eslint/parser --dev
npm add eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin --dev
```

At this point I'm getting the error above.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're facing dependency resolution issues while installing ESLint for your TypeScript/React project. The error suggests a conflict between the versions of **@typescript-eslint/parser** required by your root project and the one needed by **@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin**. To resolve this, you can try using the --legacy-peer-deps flag with the npm install command.

Here's the updated command:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

This flag allows npm to use an older, more permissive algorithm for resolving peer dependencies, which might help in cases where the strict resolution is causing conflicts.

Comment: Hey thanks for you message! Im running into the same problem again, with exactly the same error message.
Looking forward to downgrade from node 20 to an older LTS version. Hope this might fix the problem!